# Fixed Size for UIImageView Inside UITableViewCell in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using the default UITableViewCell which comes with UIImageView, titleLabel and also a description Label. I want to have a fixed size for my UIImageView so all the images are of the same size. At present it looks like this:

[image]

The row height for the cell is "Automatic" and here are the properties of the UITableView.

[image]

How can I make my UIImageView fixed size?

The images are downloaded asynchronously as shown below:

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let dish = self.dishes[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = dish.title
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dish.description

        cell.imageView?.setImageFor(url: URL(string: dish.imageURL)!) { image in
            cell.imageView?.image = image
            cell.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cell.imageView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
            cell.imageView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
        }

        return cell

    }
```

**UIImageView+Additions.swift**

```
func setImageFor(url :URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {

        DispatchQueue.global().async {

            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

            if let data = data {

                let image = UIImage(data: data)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    completion(image!)

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try to set `imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`.

Comment: I did that it did nothing!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the `height anchor` and `width anchor` of your `UIImageView` inside your `completion block handler`. You should not do that, and if you need to, make sure you are updating your layout in the `main thread`.

Your `UIImageView`'s `top, bottom, leading, and trailing anchor` might be equal to the `superView`, in your case, it's the `tableViewCell` and given that your `UITableViewCell`s have auto height. These result to unequal size of your `UIImageView`.

Since you are using interface builder, try to layout your `UIImageView` like so:

[image]

As you can see, I have my fixed width and height of my `UIImageView`.

Lastly, don't forget to set your `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` and tick `clipToBounds` to yes.

Comment: Thanks! The imageView.image is set inside the main thread. I have pasted the code for setImageURL. For some reason I cannot set any constraints on the UIImageView as shown in the picture. Once, again I am using a default UITableViewCell and not creating the prototype cell. Maybe it is a bug in Xcode 9.

Comment: You can :) . Click your TableViewCell and set its `style` to Custom. Try it.

Comment: If I style to custom then I cannot set anything! Thats okay. I will just create a custom prototype cell and use it.

Comment: It's up to you. Just don't forget to register your custom UITableViewCell to your UITableView and select a helpful answer :)

Comment: I had everything setup but still struggling with it. As my images have a vertical orientation, it always expanded to cell's height despite fixed height constraints. **clipToBounds** did the trick!